# Create new values based on length of a string in R?

Tags: r, string, nchar

I have a problem where I need to, ideally, create new values and new rows based on the length of a string.

This is my source data:

```
NumericCode1=c("12345","1234")
NumericCode2=c("0123.45","123.4")
AlphaCode=c("","")
df=data.frame(NumericCode1,NumericCode2,AlphaCode)
```

What I'd like to do is process this data using this logic:

If either of the values in NumericCode1 or NumericCode2 are greater than 5 (counting numbers only), then I'd like to populate AlphaCode with AA:BB:CC values for each. So the df would end up looking like this:

```
NumericCode1=c("12345","1234")
NumericCode2=c("0123.45","123.4")
AlphaCode=c("AA:BB:CC","")
df=data.frame(NumericCode1,NumericCode2,AlphaCode)
```

Then I could use this code to create a separate record for each and would get my desired output.

```
df %>% 
  separate_rows(AlphaCode, sep=":")

  NumericCode1 NumericCode2 AlphaCode
1        12345      0123.45        AA
2        12345      0123.45        BB
3        12345      0123.45        CC
4         1234        123.4
```

My problem is I'm stuck at the first step. I can count the characters in the strings using `nchar` or `str_lenght`, but I cannot figure out how to "*count if > 5 then do this*".

Any help much appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by "populate AlphaCode with AA:BB:CC values for each". Is there a logic to the AlphaCode inserted into the appropriate rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `stringr::str_count` and `\\d` we can count numbers only

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(Cond=if_else(str_count(NumericCode1,'\\d')>5|str_count(NumericCode2,'\\d')>5 ,
                           'AA:BB:CC',''))

   NumericCode1 NumericCode2   Cond
1        12345      0123.45    AA:BB:CC
2         1234        123.4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace`

```
cond <- nchar(sub("\\D", "", df$NumericCode1)) > 5 | nchar(sub("\\D", "", df$NumericCode2)) > 5
df$AlphaCode <- replace(df$AlphaCode,
                        cond,
                        "AA:BB:CC")
df
#  NumericCode1 NumericCode2 AlphaCode
#1        12345      0123.45  AA:BB:CC
#2         1234        123.4
```

The condition says if either `NumericCode1` or `NumericCode2` has more than 5 characters - numbers only - replace the `""` by `AA:BB:CC`.

**data**

```
df = data.frame(NumericCode1, NumericCode2, AlphaCode, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```